# Hyperref problem with enumerated tabularx rows

Tags: tables, hyperref, counters, tabularx

I was trying to do an enumeration with columns, which references one item from another one in the same list. I figured out that the best way is to make a table with enumerated rows. I had a working solution, however next thing I tried to do was to add PDF references with `hyperref` package. However, this produces quite strange results.

My solution is three column table: first one is right-aligned for the number of the row, next one has some specified length and the third one uses all the remaining space, therefore `tabularx` is needed. A short code sample:

```
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\newcounter{hdItemCounter}
\setcounter{hdItemCounter}{0}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{}rp{50pt}X}
    \refstepcounter{hdItemCounter}\thehdItemCounter.\label{hdItem1} & Some text to fill at least two lines. & Some text\\
    \refstepcounter{hdItemCounter}\thehdItemCounter.\label{hdItem2} & Some text. & Some text\\
    \refstepcounter{hdItemCounter}\thehdItemCounter.\label{hdItem3} & Some text. & Some text \ref{hdItem2} ir \ref{hdItem1}\\
    \refstepcounter{hdItemCounter}\thehdItemCounter.\label{hdItem4} & Some text. & Some text\\
    \refstepcounter{hdItemCounter}\thehdItemCounter.\label{hdItem5} & Some text. & Some text \ref{hdItem3} ir \ref{hdItem4} \\
\end{tabularx}
%Some text to fill at least several pages to see the strange effect with hyperref.
\end{document}
```

I need a lot of such tables, therefore, I created new environment and new `\item`-style command:

```
\newenvironment{someenvironment}[1]%
    {\tabularx{\textwidth}{@{}rp{#1}X}}
    {\endtabularx}
\newcommand{\someitem}[1]{\refstepcounter{hdItemCounter}\thehdItemCounter.\label{#1} &}
```

First I was trying to do this with `listliketab`, but I wasn't able to put it inside my new environment. However, even without the new environment `hyperref` acts strangely. All the references are produced, however they point to wrong places: top of the page is at the line bottom and not at the top:

[image]

This can be changed by changing the type of first column to `p`:

```
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{}p{10pt}p{50pt}X}
```

But then again - I need right-aligned first column. Nevertheless, this produces even stranger results: now references point to the top of the number, but the number is placed not at the top of the row:

[image]

This problem can be solved by writing something in front of `\refstepcounter`:

```
I\refstepcounter{hdItemCounter}\thehdItemCounter.\label{hdItem1}
```

By the way, \phantom{I} does not work, however forced space symbol does:

```
\ \refstepcounter{hdItemCounter}\thehdItemCounter.\label{hdItem1}
```

I am sorry for the lengthy post, but I wanted to be as specific as I can. Can anyone, please, suggest a better solution to my problem? I need every `pt` of the page width in order to display formulas as clearly as possible, therefore it would be very nice to have the `r` column and avoid putting space in every line.

I will be really grateful for any help and comments.

Answer (score 1):

To specify the alignment of a column of the type `p{<width>}` you can insert different declarations with the command `>{decl.}`.

To get a right align column with a specific width set `>{\raggedleft}p{10pt}`

To simplify the modification you can use the following table header:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\newcounter{hdItemCounter}
\setcounter{hdItemCounter}{0}
\usepackage{showframe}
\begin{document}

\noindent\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}%
  {@{\makebox[30pt][l]{\refstepcounter{hdItemCounter}\thehdItemCounter.\label{hdItem\thehdItemCounter}}}p{50pt}X}
Some text to fill at least two lines. & Some text\\
Some text. & Some text\\
Some text. & Some text \ref{hdItem2} ir \ref{hdItem1}\\
Some text. & Some text\\
Some text. & Some text \ref{hdItem3} ir \ref{hdItem4} \\
\end{tabularx}
Some text to fill at least several pages to see the strange effect with hyperref.
\end{document}
```

This can be simplified by your own environment:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\newcounter{hdItemCounter}
\setcounter{hdItemCounter}{0}
\usepackage{showframe}
\newenvironment{specifictable}{%
\tabularx\linewidth{@{\makebox[30pt][l]{\refstepcounter{hdItemCounter}\thehdItemCounter.\label{hdItem\thehdItemCounter}}}p{50pt}X}}{\endtabularx}
\begin{document}

\noindent\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}%
  {@{\makebox[30pt][l]{\refstepcounter{hdItemCounter}\thehdItemCounter.\label{hdItem\thehdItemCounter}}}p{50pt}X}
Some text to fill at least two lines. & Some text\\
Some text. & Some text\\
Some text. & Some text \ref{hdItem2} ir \ref{hdItem1}\\
Some text. & Some text\\
Some text. & Some text \ref{hdItem3} ir \ref{hdItem4} \\
\end{tabularx}
Some text to fill at least several pages to see the strange effect with hyperref.

\noindent\begin{specifictable}
Some text to fill at least two lines. & Some text\\
Some text. & Some text\\
Some text. & Some text \ref{hdItem2} ir \ref{hdItem1}\\
Some text. & Some text\\
Some text. & Some text \ref{hdItem3} ir \ref{hdItem4} \\
\end{specifictable}
\end{document}
```

The code above produces:
[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However, it doesn't solve my problem. The solution with the box produces a correct looking table, however if you try to push on number 1 in the PDF, it directs you to the line "to fill at" instead of directing to the first line.

If the start of the environment is changed to: `\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{}>{\raggedleft}p{10pt}p{50pt}X}`, then the table is corrupted. I will try and experiment with it more on Monday. Thanks for your effort.

Comment: My solution was to use `>{\raggedleft}p{...}` and to start every line with `\noindent`:  
    `\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|@{}>{\raggedleft}p{14pt}@{}|p{50pt}|X|}   \noindent\refstepcounter{hdItemCounter}\thehdItemCounter.\label{hdItem1}`. I don't know, why it works and why omitting `\noindent` brakes the table. It was just a result of trial and error. So thanks for you help.